# How to convert HTML To PDF and open pdf file, using java with YaHP Html to Pdf Convertor

Tags: java, pdf

Am using a YaHP-Converter to convert HTML File to Pdf. Here is the code example i have used for converting. The code works me fine. But i want open Pdf file after this conversion.
Any idea please.

```
CYaHPConverter converter = new CYaHPConverter();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pdfOut);
Map properties = new HashMap();
List headerFooterList = new ArrayList();
properties.put(IHtmlToPdfTransformer.PDF_RENDERER_CLASS,IHtmlToPdfTransformer.FLYINGSAUCER_PDF_RENDERER);
converter.convertToPdf(htmlContents,
            IHtmlToPdfTransformer.LEGALL,
            headerFooterList,
            "file:///D:/temp/",
            out,
            properties);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think this helps:

```
                import java.io.File;
                import java.io.FileOutputStream;
                import java.util.ArrayList;
                import java.util.HashMap;
                import java.util.List;
                import java.util.Map;
                import java.util.Scanner;


                // http://www.allcolor.org/YaHPConverter/
                import org.allcolor.yahp.converter.CYaHPConverter;
                import org.allcolor.yahp.converter.IHtmlToPdfTransformer;

                public class HtmlToPdf_yahp_2 {
                  public  static void main(String ... args ) throws Exception {
                    String root = "c:/temp/html";
                    String input = "file_1659686.htm";  // need to be charset utf-8
                    htmlToPdfFile(new File(root, input),
                                  new File(root, input + ".pdf"));
                    System.out.println("Done");
                  }

                  public static void htmlToPdfFile(File htmlIn, File pdfOut) throws Exception {
                    Scanner scanner =
                       new Scanner(htmlIn).useDelimiter("\\Z");
                    String htmlContents = scanner.next();

                    CYaHPConverter converter = new CYaHPConverter();
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pdfOut);
                    Map properties = new HashMap();
                    List headerFooterList = new ArrayList();

                    properties.put(IHtmlToPdfTransformer.PDF_RENDERER_CLASS,
                                   IHtmlToPdfTransformer.FLYINGSAUCER_PDF_RENDERER);
                    //properties.put(IHtmlToPdfTransformer.FOP_TTF_FONT_PATH, fontPath);
                    converter.convertToPdf(htmlContents,
                                IHtmlToPdfTransformer.A4P,
                                headerFooterList,
                                "file:///temp/html/",
                                out,
                                properties);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                  }
                }
```

See this for futher info:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-convert-html-to-pdf-using-yahp.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. With your reference i have created pdf file successfully. But i need to open that file automatically after creating it. because the above code only create the pdf file. Not open the file automatically. Any idea please.